# Router.push behavior change after next upgrade from 9.1.1 to 9.5.3 and next-transpile-modules 3.3.0 to 7.3.0

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been bumping a few libraries in my Web app and noticed one of the pages that relied on redirects using Router.push() stopped working after the upgrade.
The bumps were:

- next: 9.1.1 to 9.5.3
- next-transpile-modules 3.3.0 to 7.3.0

The scenario is:

- /path/[id] Loads, user interacts with it, presses next
- Router.push is called changing the id for the page
- The page used to load normally for the id + n page, but what happens now is the URL changes but the page doesn't get rerendered in any form

I have downgraded both libraries and retested and I'm positive this is the change that did it. I looked for migration guides and the issues in the 9.5.0 release but couldn't find anything relevant.

Any ideas what changed?

This is the push call and this is a class component:

```
import Router from 'next/router';
...
Router.push({
  pathname: `/path/${newId}`,
  query: {
  // different params
  },
  shallow: false,
});
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me figure it out https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2819.
I just needed to make the Component unique to make sure componentDidMount executes again. Not sure why this broke after these specific version changes, as the post is using a much older Next version, but it's fixed. Leaving this up for everyone else with this very specific version issue.

Fix:
On the appropriate file on the pages/ folder, eg: `pages/path/[id].js`

`<Component key={any unique key}/>`